# How to flatten/split items in list that are separated by " and '

Tags: python, regex, nested-lists

I have the following list

```
mylist = ["'alpha','beta'",'delta','phi']
```

The combination of double quotes and single quotes for the first element is preventing me from properly working with alpha and beta separately.
When i use

```
mylist[1]
```

i get

```
delta
```

instead of beta, which is what i want

How do I split the first element of this list into 2 items and reinsert them so that I have have 4 items in this list?

Before you tell me not to write a list in this way, know that it is an output of a single line that i have already split from

```
"'alpha, beta'"
```

**EDIT:** Many of you are asking for the code that forms this list.... and I honestly couldn't post it because part of the code requires logging into a web-site to access restricted data.

The following code solved my problem:

```
mylist = [re.sub('^\W+|\W+$', '', i) for b in map(lambda x:re.split(',', x), mylist) for i in b]
```

Comment: Show the code that's creating the list, that would be the better place to solve this.

Comment: It would help to know how you got to this point. Where does this data come from? Can you share the original format and what steps you've taken to get it into this form?

Comment: Doing it at this point is likely to be very fragile. What happens if there are literal quotes or commas that need to be retained in the list elements? You'll need to deal with escaping them, and then parsing that when flattening.

Comment: `re.findall(r'\w+', ','.join(x))`

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `map`:

```
import re

def split_words(d):
  return [re.sub('^\W+|\W+$', '', i) for b in map(lambda x:re.split("(?<='),(?=')", x), d) for i in b]

mylist = [["'alpha','beta'",'delta','phi'], ["'alpha','beta'",'delta','phi, theta']]
final_results = list(map(split_words, mylist))
```

Output:

```
[['alpha', 'beta', 'delta', 'phi'], ['alpha', 'beta', 'delta', 'phi, theta']]
```

Comment: This works for the intended example. Where can I make it so that it only does this for the first iteration? It's splitting all commas down the line in other strings that i wish to keep.

    `mylist = ["'alpha','beta'",'delta','phi, theta']` 
Where i want to split alpha and beta, but keep 'phi, theta'

Comment: @JustinKhine Please see my recent edit. I added your two input samples into one list, and applied a function with the updated `re.split` to each.

Answer (score 0):

Another one using regular expressions: You could just `findall` the words `\w+` in the strings:

```
>>> mylist = ["'alpha','beta'",'delta','phi']

>>> [y for x in mylist for y in re.findall("\w+", x)]
['alpha', 'beta', 'delta', 'phi']
```

Or `split` by everything else `\W`, or more specifically `[,"' ]`:

```
>>> [y for x in mylist for y in re.split("\W", x) if y]
['alpha', 'beta', 'delta', 'phi']

>>> [y for x in mylist for y in re.split("[,'\" ]", x) if y]
['alpha', 'beta', 'delta', 'phi']
```

Comment: This works only if each element is a single word, such as in my example. But some elements in my actual data are strings that must not be split up.
But this will help for other reasons. Thank you!